# How Spring Caching works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

How is the @Cacheable annotation notified about the changes in the database. For eg : If I Cache the result of CRUDRepository.findAll() function call by annotating the function call by @Cacheable the result is stored in a named cache. The Cache however continues to be updated with DB changes. Consider the below example :

```
@Cacheable(value = "employee", key = "#id")
public Iterable<Employee> getAllEmployees(){                 
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Iterable<Employee>  itr = employeeEntityRepository.findAll();
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time-->" + (stopTime - startTime));
    return itr;
}
```

When this method is called the first time it takes 300 ms and the 2nd time it takes hardly 5 ms which means it Caches the result set. Fair enough. But now if I update a record in the employee table directly in the DB and call this method again two things happen :

1. The new record is returned by this method call.
2. The method returns very fast.

This means that the cache is updated from the DB every time. How does this Sync work if the resultset is returned from Cache ?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have `CachePut` in your code that updates the DB ?

Comment: No. It even gets the records that you put in the DB through SQL Editor.

Comment: When does your cache expire or evict ?

Comment: I figured out Marged. The problem is with the key. If I give a constant number as Key(suppose 100) the result is Cached and the method is not invoked again and again. I am wondering what could be a possible Key for such a method.

Comment: @Geek Where is the #id coming from. I don't see any input to the method from where it could have been placed? Also, would recommend you to answer your own question if you found a solution to it.

Comment: Also, let's say we have millions of records on the table and I want to get `select count` every 5 secs. And I don't want to connect the database for each query for CPU usage of my database server. How does Spring Cache work? Is it checks for new records periodically on the table?

Answer (score 0):

The main question is:  cache is updated from the DB every time. How does this Sync work if the resultset is returned from Cache?

As per spring doc (5.3.7) @Cacheable annotation is used when we need to cache the result of a call.

in the above scenario caching behavior will be applied, it's checked if the method was already invoked for the given arguments.

below attributes are used in your example. Their description is as below:

1. value : this name of cache, in above case its "employee"
2. Key : this is SpEl, Spring Expression Language, to compute the key dynamically.

Ideally, you should have "id" as method-argument in the method getAllEmployees().
But this method seems to return all employees, so it seems incorrect usage in this scenario.

SpEl expression is "#id" = a custom key generator

By default it is "" = all method parameter are considered as key.

If no value is found in the cache for the computed key, the target method will be invoked and returned value will be stored in the associated cache.

The scenario which I encountered is that the method which is annotated by @Cacheable

```
    @Cacheable(value= myConstant,key="#accountId")
public Integer getAccountNumber( Integer accountId){. 
// an API call is made here..}
```

So, cache is not updated from DB, it's updated from a call (API call) next, the result is stored in the cache when the method is invoked for the first time. When the method is called a second time the cached result is returned and API call in the method do not happen.

I have referred: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html